# Email Validation in Javascript based upon domain look up

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this question has been posted many times. But still i would like to inquire a little more. I have used a function

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){  
       var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;  
         return emailPattern.test(elementValue);  
    }
```

It works fine. But my problem is that it allows 123@123.com as a valid email. So i want to check the domain also like checkdnsrr() does in php. Can i do it in javascript? I want to check for valid domain also.

Comment: `Can i do it in javascript?` What are you asking about?

Comment: I am asking that can the domain of an email be validated in javascript ? Like 123@123.com should be invalid email as there is no 123 domain.

Comment: I dont think you could do that with just JS..

Comment: No. Not in unassisted JS. Ajax the address to your server and do a checkdnsrr there and return true or false

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no other solution than using AJAX to do this.

You do a request on your server with JS, the server checks the DNS using `checkdnsrr()`, and it responds with whatever you want, it will allow your JS to handle the validation depending on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in php? That will be much easier than making an ajax call.

Comment: Without reloading the page? And if you already do it in php, why not Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

On the same code that you have Provided

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){  
   var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;  
     return emailPattern.test(elementValue);  
}
```

Change it in this manner and it will validate 123@123.com Checking that the Domain can not be @123.com

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){  
   var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;  
     return emailPattern.test(elementValue);  
}
```